# android - GPS not accurate

Tags: android, gps, coordinates

i am trying to show on the map where i am.
I am in Israel and it shows me i am in Egypt.
I tried implementing all of the suggestions of different posts and non helped me solve my problem.

- I turned on GPS.
- I am connected to the Internet.
- When i launch MAPS default android App it shows my real location!

MANIFEST PERMISSIONS:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

I also use the uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps".

This is the relevant code from the MapActivity which extends LocationListener:

```
        lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    boolean enabled = lm
      .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    // Check if enabled and if not send user to the GSP settings
    // Better solution would be to display a dialog and suggesting to 
    // go to the settings
    if (!enabled) {
      Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
      startActivity(intent);
    } 


    if(came_from.matches("FollowLocation"))
    {
        Location location;
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
        String providerName = lm.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
        // If no suitable provider is found, null is returned.
        if (providerName == null) 
        {
            // reflecting changes if distance travel by
            // user is greater than 20m from current location
            // and every 1 minute
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
            location=lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        }
        else
        {
            // reflecting changes if distance travel by
            // user is greater than 20m from current location
            // and every 1 minute
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(providerName, 1*60*1000, 20, this);
            location=lm.getLastKnownLocation(providerName);
        }       


        gMapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.myGMap);
        gMapView.setStreetView(true);
        mc = gMapView.getController();
        if (location != null)   
        {
            lat = location.getLatitude();
            lng = location.getLongitude();
            mc.setZoom(14);
        }
        else    //in case we didn't get the location yet
        {
            lat = 32.08;
            lng = 35.84;
            mc.setZoom(9);
        }

        p = new GeoPoint((int) lat * 1000000, (int) lng * 1000000);
        mc.animateTo(p);

        // Adding zoom controls to Map
        gMapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        // Add a location mark
        MyLocationOverlay myLocationOverlay = new MyLocationOverlay();
        List<Overlay> list = gMapView.getOverlays();
        list.add(myLocationOverlay);



    }

}

/* This method is called when use position will get changed */
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    if (location != null) {
        double lat = location.getLatitude();
        double lng = location.getLongitude();
        p = new GeoPoint((int) lat * 1000000, (int) lng * 1000000);
        mc.animateTo(p);
    }
}




public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // required for interface, not used
}

public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // required for interface, not used
}

public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // required for interface, not used
}

protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    return false;
}
```

These coordinates: lat = 32.08 lng = 35.84  are some spot in israel...
So..... What am i doing wrong ? Or what am i doing not right ? :P

Thanks!

Comment: You're not using an iPhone 5 are you?

Comment: Sorry, my poor attempt at humour...I was only joking..

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that getLastKnownLocation is giving you that erroneous position for some reason. Your default of 32.08, 35.84 won't ever get reached because location will never be null. I'd suggest using the debugger to see which of your calls to getLastKnownLocation is getting hit, and what the value returned is.

Comment: The value returned is not where i am. This is because the onLocationChanged returned a wrong value the last time. I also tried applying the application from a different place in Israel and it put me in a different place in the sea !

Answer (score 0):

I took my code and compared it to a working code from an example in the internet.
Not sure what solved the problem, but i definetly know that you should requestLocationUpdates after you finish to configure everything else.

Other people who encounter this problem - try taking a working code from the internet and comparing it step by step until it works on your app.